# Block an action from executing via Javascript Function

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have the following commandLink

```
<apex:commandLink value="Save" onClick="Validation();" action="{!ActionMethod}" />
```

When it's clicked,  I would like to stop the action from executing by returning false.

```
function Validation() {
        return false;
}
```

The above method does not work, but if I put return false directly in the onClick attribute the behaviour works as expected:

```
<apex:commandLink value="Save" onClick="return false;" action="{!ActionMethod}" />
```

Is there a way I can pass this return value up to the onClick attr?

**Gist Edit**

```
<apex:commandLink value="Save" onclick="return Validation();" action="{!saveSettings}"/>                        


function Validation() {              
  alert('returning false');   
  return false;                    
}


// Alert shows 'returning false', action still executes.
```

Comment: Have you tried putting return Vslidation(); in the onclick? Iirc when false it will stop the action

Comment: @Eric If I put return false; in the onClick attribute it works as expected, but the above code in my OP doesn't work. Am I returning the false wrong somehow?

Comment: See my answer. You are forgetting the `return` part in the onClick

Comment: Try removing the alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
<apex:commandLink value="Save" onClick="return Validation();" action="{!ActionMethod}" />
```

Add the return to the onClick. When Validation return false the onClick will then return false thus preventing the action from occurring

Comment: While that does make sense, when I tried it doesn't seem to work. I have created a gist showing my current code

https://gist.github.com/SamCousinsGB/81fba7c0ea5a0613703c928e2f77c9aa

Comment: @SamC - Sorry I do not do/look at gists here. The whole point is to post your code here not make users goto an external link.

Comment: My mistake, I will edit my OP

Answer (score 0):

It's better to move the validation into the 'form' tag:

```
<apex:form id="form" onSubmit="return Validation();">
```

Comment: It does prevent action from submitting. Validating the form assumes that every action requires the validation

Comment: @Eric, you right, I've tested it. The main point is that the result of Validation function must be returned. But I think validation on submit action is better because user can submit the form by pressing Enter button rather than clicking the button.

Comment: Depending on the situation you are correct. But this would limit you to always performing the validation for every action. Sometimes a Form performs many actions and not every one of them could require validation (Like in actionfunction called from oncomplete...Good points nonetheless and a workable solution

Comment: Good point, I have no objections.

Comment: Thank you for your input maovrn, this will be useful for another element of my project!

Answer (score -1):

You can make it work like this

```
<apex:commandLink value="Save" onClick="Validation();"/>
```

In your javascript

```
function Validation() 
{
    var isvalidForm = true;
    //Validation code goes here
    if(Form is not valid)
    {
        isvalidForm = false;
    }
    if(isvalidForm)
    {
        Actionfunc();
    }
}
```

In your visualforce page

```
<apex:actionFunction name="Actionfunc" action="ActionMethod"/>
```

Hope this will solve your problem, ActionMethod gets executed only when it returns true. When it returns false ActionMethod will not be callled.

Comment: While this works it adds unnecessary elements/complexity to the page

Comment: Elements are added on the cost of functionality, that can't be achieved through the way you told. It provides the better client-side form validations.

Comment: Um. The answer I provided works just fine. And no your answer does not provide any better validation it just modifies the flow

Comment: Yeah I know, but your answer is not providing any validation.

Comment: The question was not about how to validate inputs and the op has a function for that. And for what it's worth, this answer does not provide any validation